# How to align text to different sides of the same line

Tags: html

How do I align text to different sides of the same line without using CSS?

```
<p align="left">To the left</p>
<p align="right">To the right</p>
```

That's what I'm using right now to align text to different sides, but if I use that it automatically goes to the next line. I do NOT want to use any CSS for this.

Comment: `<p>` is a block-element. Use `<span>`; it's inline. But it won't line the text out for you yet tho. And what's the problem with CSS?

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: Your knowledge of HTML and the DOM is insufficient. I don't understand why you do NOT want to use any CSS. `<span></span><span></span>`. But if you want to align the text too, you need a relative parent with a given width and make the `<span>`'s `inline-block` so they can accept a 50% width to fill up that space.

Comment: Perhaps you can let us know the reason for the CSS restriction. Generally, if we know why the restriction we can find a way around it, but blatantly stating that you simply don't want to use it, isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a `<div>` or a `<p>`for this; it's a block element. Try using `<span>`s instead. Also, use CSS for your text align, like this

```
<span id="left">To the left</span>
<span id="right">To the right</span>
```

And in your CSS

```
#left{
     float:left;
}
#right{
     float:right;
}
```

Comment: You can achieve very little without CSS. You're too naive and hardly seem to understand how DOM works at all. What are you aiming to achieve with the code? Also StackOverflow isn't a cookbook website.

Comment: `align` has been deprecated for a while now. It won't even work in HTML5. Why don't you want to use CSS?

Comment: <sarcasm>Perhaps you want to use tables?</sarcasm>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <span align="left">To the left</span>
 <span align="right">To the right</span>
```

This automatically displays it inline.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can write it without CSS, using HTML only.

```
<p style="text-align:left">To the left</p>

<p style="text-align:right">To the right</p>
```

But if you want the text aligned in the same line you would need to use CSS.

```
HTML:

<div id="textbox">
<p class="alignleft">Text on the left.</p>
<p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
</div>

CSS:
.alignleft {
float: left;
}
.alignright {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Well, that is CSS of course.  But it's integrated into the HTML so it doesn't require a separate CSS file.

Comment: He doesn't want to use a separate file, but even using it wont align it in the same line, he would have to use CSS or make a table.